# Can't get JSON results from file in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm having problems getting my request filled with the data from a json file... Data is pulled from Mysql DB and formatted in a JSON file in the scripts dir...

Could there be a problem with the GET request ? I just want the json file returned so i could work with the key/val pairs inside of it ...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
function fetchData($str){

    $queryAll = "select name,value,date from chart where id <= (select max(id) from chart) limit 50";

    $dateValue = mysql_query($queryAll);
    $pushed = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dateValue,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $key = array_shift($row);
        $value = array_shift($row);
        $date = array_shift($row);

        if(strcmp("$str",$key) == 0){
            $myArray = array($key, $value, $date);
            array_push($pushed,$myArray);
         }
    }
    $jsonFile = json_encode($pushed);
    $jsonOpenFile = fopen("../scripts/$str.json","w+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    $jsonWriteOut = fwrite($jsonOpenFile,$jsonFile);

}
fetchData("blabla");
?>
```

```
<script>

function Graph(JsonVal){

    var xmlhttp = new ajaxRequest();

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var jsondata=eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");
            var returned = jsondata.items
            var output; 
            for(var i=0; i<returned.length;i++){
                output += "<p>";
                output += returned[i];
                output += "</p>";
             }
             document.getElementById("MyGraph").innerHTML=output
         }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","../scripts/"+JsonVal+".json",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

</script>

<div id="MyGraph" onload="Graph();"></div>
```

Comment: Lots less typing (and much easier format, IMO) with jQuery/AJAX... Just saying... Tons of examples on here to search.

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? What happens and what do you expect to happen? It's a lot easier for us to help you when we know what is wrong.

Comment: `eval` can be very dangerous. If you're expecting JSON data you can use `JSON.parse` if your browser supports it, or a library like [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), or [jQuery](http://jquery.com). jQuery will simplify your AJAX calls too.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips already...

Comment: My question is if i can work this way because i can't get results in the xmlhttp.responseText?

Comment: how does the xmlhttp.open get the json into xmlhttp.responseText? Do i need to write some external php to accomplish this or does it get filled just with what's inside the requested GET file